# How to logout from a controller with Spring Security

Tags: grails, grails-spring-security

Is there a logout method for Spring Security that I can use in a controller? Or is there a way to logout by clearing the cache and refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails controllers have a [`request`](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/request.html) object available in them that is an instance of `HttpServletRequest`. You can use this to log the current user out by calling the [`logout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout%28%29) method on it.

```
class TestController {

    def logMeOut() {
        request.logout() // Logout current user
        redirect(controller: 'home', action: 'index') // Redirect to the home page
    }
}
```

Spring Security adds a little [more information on the logout method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#servletapi-logout).

Comment: Also please check the state for your *session* object and call *session.invalidate()* if need